# Facing problem with PM2 server throwing Javascript heap out of memory on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am tyring since last night but just not able to get around this problem. I am currently deploying a NodeJs application on ec2 instance and it is built using Typescript. The server has 8gb ram and 30 gb storage and is having NodeJs v16.15.0.

So basically this is the command that is run on the dev server using PM2:

```
"npm run build && NODE_ENV=dev node build/server.js"
```

where `npm run build` intially runs this:

```
"NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 tsc"
```

To execute these commands on EC2 intance I use pm2 command `pm2 start npm -- run dev` and while it runs perfectly fine on the other ec2 instances, somehow this time it is continuously failing. Here is the error:

```
0|npm  | <--- Last few GCs --->
0|npm  | [20552:0x5441560]   258502 ms: Mark-sweep 4035.0 (4136.0) -> 4021.0 (4137.2) MB, 7015.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.098, current mu = 0.035) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
0|npm  | [20552:0x5441560]   265432 ms: Mark-sweep 4037.2 (4137.2) -> 4023.1 (4139.0) MB, 6628.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.072, current mu = 0.044) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
0|npm  | <--- JS stacktrace --->
0|npm  | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
0|npm  |  1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [node]
0|npm  |  2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
0|npm  |  3: 0xcf8dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
0|npm  |  4: 0xcf9137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
0|npm  |  5: 0xeb09d5  [node]
0|npm  |  6: 0xeb14b6  [node]
0|npm  |  7: 0xebf9de  [node]
0|npm  |  8: 0xec0420 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
0|npm  |  9: 0xec339e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
0|npm  | 10: 0xe848da v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
0|npm  | 11: 0x11fd626 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
0|npm  | 12: 0x15f2099  [node]
0|npm  | sh: line 1: 20541 Aborted                 npm run build
```

If I still try to run `Tsc` and `NODE_ENV=dev node build/server.js` without pm2 everthing gets executed normally, just that as soon as I invoke these commands with pm2 it throws this error

**What I Tried**

Tried all solutions e.g. putting `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096` before tsc command then also putting `--max-old-space-size=4096` before node build/server.js. I also tried increasing the memory allocation to pm2 using `pm2 start npm --node-args="--max-old-space-size=2048" -- run dev`.

But nothing works in my case. Is this due to pm2 running out of heap? I am finding it very hard to understand this error log.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who are also facing this problem, I solved it by downgrading the PM2 version from 5.2.0 to 5.1.2 and surprisingly it worked.

I believe it has more to do with my application not matching the requirements of latest version from PM2. I still don't understand how is this working with 5.1.2.

Comment: Did not actually address, the problem. Tried to downgrade to 5.1.2, but still getting the error you described. I also tried same thing without luck. Probably you did something else while downgrading.

Comment: Apart from this I only downgraded my Node version from v14 (latest at that time) to v12